# Classpath contains only the running file

Tags: java, jdbc, classpath, connector-j

I'm having issues trying to use the Connector/J JDBC driver in my code.

The code I have written uses the `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance()` to load the class before `DriverManager.getConnection()` is used to load the driver.

This results in the ClassNotFoundException for com.mydql.jdbc.Driver. I have the binary JAR file for the mysql connector, `mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar`.

My code is packaged into a JAR file by building in Netbeans.

To run the code I am using the following

```
java -classpath "/path/to/mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar" -jar MyJarFile.jar
```

This gives the exception: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Adding `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));` to the beginning of the program prints only `MyJarFile.jar`.

I have tried adding the jar file to the CLASSPATH variable using export, and setting the last part of the `-classpath` flag to `lib/*`, but with the same results.

I tried running the program from a .class file, instead. It complained about being unable to find or load the main class. It would run only when both the wildcard was used in the classpath and the MyJarFile.jar was in that location. It would simply hang at the loading of the Driver, though.

Does anyone have any thoughts as to what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try don't mix -cp and -jar options, this might work:

```
java -cp "mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar:MyJarFile.jar" my.package.Main
```

for *nix or

```
java -cp "mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar;MyJarFile.jar" my.package.Main
```

for windows

where `my.package.Main` is your main class.

Comment: This works with loading the program from the terminal. Now to solve why it hangs at `DriverManager.getConnection()`. Thanks!